# Uso e significato di "guizzo" in questo passaggio

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Forse feci un movimento sbagliato, non so, di certo avvertii un **guizzo** dolorosissimo al centro della natica destra che si allungò lungo la gamba come un ferro caldo. Tornai a casa zoppicando, mi misi a letto, passò.

Ho cercato "guizzo" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può significare un movimento rapido, ma qui sembra piuttosto qualcosa simile a un dolore improvviso. È così? È comune usare il termine "guizzo" con lo stesso senso del brano oppure si tratta di un uso letterario più o meno inventato dall'autrice?

Comment: Probabilmente “un guizzo” nel senso di “qualcosa di guizzante”, in questo caso una contrazione muscolare. Lo scivolone di “si allungò lungo” è davvero deplorevole.

Comment: Guizzo nel senso di un dolore che appare e scompare velocemente, l'analogia è con un movimento rapido, in questo caso del dolore che viene avvertito in maniera forte.

Comment: Concordo con @egreg: il guizzo è di uno dei muscoli glutei che si è contratto provocandole dolore. Non è un uso inventato dall'autrice: in certa paraletteratura (letteratura rosa, soprattutto) abbondano uomini con muscoli guizzanti (un modo per dire che sono prestanti e atletici). Qui, si prende il guizzo del muscolo e lo si usa per descrivere un dolore improvviso.

Comment: Il guizzo non è certo un muscolo (e infatti Benedetta scriveva “*di* uno dei muscoli...”) e direi neppure il dolore di per sé, e infatti è il guizzo a essere “dolorosissimo”. Direi, più o meno come detto da altri, che sia una contrazione, un accavallamento, qualcosa del genere.

Comment: @Benedetta: Quindi si tratta in un certo modo di un movimento rapido, a scatti, di un muscolo? Cioè, c'è un movimento rapido in un muscolo che provoca una lesione.

Comment: @Charo: Il guizzo è rapido, non a scatti. Hai presente come si muove la fiamma di una candela a un colpo di vento, oppure un pesce che cambia direzione o si divincola? Può succedere anche ai muscoli. Quando accade, si sente dolore, non necessariamente perché si è verificata una lesione.

Comment: @Benedetta: Nel commento precedente ho scritto "a scatti" perché, per poter capire i vostri commenti, ho dovuto cercare la definizione di "guizzare" nel vocabolario Treccani e là ho letto "muoversi dimenandosi a scatti e ..." (movimento di alcuni pesci e altri movimenti simili, come tu hai spiegato molto bene). Adesso, però, penso di capire il senso, ma si dovrebbe scrivere la risposta.

Answer (score 1):

La parola *guizzo* indica uno scatto o un salto (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/guizzo/). In questo caso è usato un po' in libertà per indicare una **[fitta](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/fitta)** o, più precisamente, un **mioclono** (un innocuo spasmo involontario di un muscolo, http://www.medicina360.com/mioclonie-spasmi-muscolari.html): il/la protagonista ha avvertito una fitta, arrivata senza preavviso e accompagnata da un dolore pungente.

Visto che guizzo è un po' fuori luogo in una frase del genere, la scrittrice ha bisogno dell'aggettivo "doloroso" per fare capire al lettore a cosa si riferisce.

Comment: E se vogliamo fare un po' di dietrologia, _guizzo_ ha origine nel verbo tedesco _[witschen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/witschen)_ [secondo etimo.it](http://www.etimo.it/?term=guizzare), verbo che potrebbe far parte del lessico familiare di Elena Ferrante (se accettiamo l'ipotesi che sia lo pseudonimo di Anita Raja).

Comment: Vallo a sapere! (che "guizzare" provenga dal tedesco -- secondo il Treccani l'etimologia è incerta e secondo [quest'altro vocabolario](https://books.google.es/books?id=DsxFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=guizzare+etimo&source=bl&ots=RBpvm0GkON&sig=CtC2Igmwwz7y23W2SD6z4wLdnxU&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZgaKEkYDQAhWGPxQKHQw3DHQQ6AEIFjAF#v=onepage&q=guizzare&f=false) ha un origine onomatopeico -- e che la Ferrante abbia qualcosa a che vedere con Anita Raja).

Comment: Veramente si tratta di un uso "fuori luogo"? Non è quello che ha detto Benedetta nei suoi commenti. Anche @Gio, nella sua risposta (che è stata cancellata), ha menzionato [questo articolo](http://m.my-personaltrainer.it/Sintomi/Fascicolazione_muscolare) che fa uso di "guizzo" in un senso simile a quello del romanzo.

Comment: @gioele: Personalmente, trovo che etimo.it sia così pieno di vecchiume e invenzioni del Pianigiani che non mi ci baserei come fonte attendibile.

Comment: @Charo: con "fuori luogo" intendo che una frase come "Forse feci un movimento sbagliato e avvertii un guizzo" (senza "doloroso") è, a mio parere, incomprensibile ai più. L'uso normale di guizzo è un altro, e normalmente un guizzo si fa, non si avverte. Questo uso di guizzo è molto molto meno frequente anche se comprensibile.

Comment: @Dag: beh, infatti è giusto una speculazione da commento. :)